# Azure VM --generate-ssh-keys, no passphrase

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, azure, ssh-keys

I've created an Azure Ubuntu VM, using azure cli with the following command:
    az vm create \
    --resource-group rgName \
    --name vmName-$RANDOM \
    --image UbuntuLTS \
    --admin-username adminName \
    --generate-ssh-keys

When attempting to ssh into the new vm with ssh adminName@, I'm presented with a login prompt to enter a passphrase.

Unfortunately, my linux user password does not unlock the private key. You can see I didn't specify a passhphrase during the VM creation.

It looks like I created some Azure SSH keys previously and this vm build process put these new ssh keys in the same key store.

How do I determine which method [from the docs I used](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/create-ssh-keys-detailed) to initially create the keys?

Comment: I am interested in the same question as I have not presented the passphrase anywhere it is not the password linked to my Azure account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CLI command [`az vm create`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-create) that you have used with the parameter `--generate-ssh-keys` will create an ssh key in the ~/.ssh.

> --generate-ssh-keys
>
> Generate SSH public and private key files if missing. The keys will be
>   stored in the ~/.ssh directory.

You can also create the ssh key yourself with the tool that you choose. And then use the parameter `--ssh-key-vaule` with your ssh key.